# How can I insert a DIV *between* an existing parent and child?

Tags: javascript, dhtml

Suppose I have a partial dom tree with a parent node and a set of children.

How can I interject a DIV between them?

I am starting with

```
parent --+--> child[0]
         |--> child[1]
         |--> child[2]
```

..and I want to end with

```
parent ---> newdiv ---+--> child[0]
                      |--> child[1]
                      |--> child[2]
```

How can I do this?

I need the converse of `replaceChild()` .  Is there something like `replaceParent()` ?

I suppose I could clone all the child nodes, and then insert them as children in the new node.   but... does that retain all the element ids?

---

**EDIT** - I didn't tag this with jQuery, or any framework, but maybe I should have been explicit about it. This is not a jQuery question. I want to do this in javascript  + DHTML. No extra or outside framework.

Comment: I think cloning all the child nodes will be your best bet... looking at the jQuery source for `wrapAll` (which I think does pretty much what you're looking for), that appears to be what is done (although I haven't analysed it thoroughly): http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.wrapAll If you can use jQuery, I'd suggest that!

Comment: Correct, `wrapAll()` does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/2U7rm/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just move elements around by appending them to a new parent. In plain javascript:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

while(parent.hasChildNodes())
    newDiv.appendChild(parent.firstChild);

parent.appendChild(newDiv);
```

From the [documentation of W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-appendChild) about `appendChild`:

> Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.

Comment: just to clarify - appending an element to a new parent, removes it's relationship with the existing parent. is that right?

Comment: @Cheeso - Yes, see the notes on https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild. It works this way in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.child').wrapAll('<div class="newdiv"></div>');
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `.firstChild`, one can also use `.firstElementChild`. The property `.firstChild` can return textNodes that just contains the formatting text from the HTML; i.e., the first child might just be a textNode with a nodeValue = `\n`        .

Consider the following snippet if you want to only move children elements, not textNodes:

```
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // Insert a new div in between a parent and its children
    while (parent.childElementCount > 0) {
        newDiv.appendChild(parentDiv.firstElementChild);
    }
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) for details on how an HTML file's whitespace can remain part of an active DOM.