# Create div as subcontainer in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, html

How to get html like this:

```
<div id="generalContainer">
    <div id="subContainer">    
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

from original html like this:

```
<div id="generalContainer">         
    <div id="content">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div id="generalContainer">         
        <div id="content">blabla</div> 
    </div>  
    <script>
        var ct = $('#generalContainer').html();
        $('#generalContainer').html('<div id="subContainer">'+ct+'</div>');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#content").wrap('<div id="subContainer">'); ​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: What if there is another div on the same level as #content, and I want to wrap them both with #subContainer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztPsE/1/) working JSFiddle.

In Short, this is the code you need:

```
$('#content').wrapAll('<div class="newdiv">Child in between</div>');
```

Also, take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700140/how-can-i-insert-a-div-between-an-existing-parent-and-child)** question posted previously.