# Display Element Between Child and Parent

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I am trying to render an element between two nested elements. This is probably best explained with an example:

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  z-index: 0;
  
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#other {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<!-- I want to have this element in between the "parent" and "child". -->
<div id="other"></div>
```

In this case, I want the green ("#other") element to be rendered in between (z-depth wise) the red parent ("#parent") and blue child ("#child") elements. In other words, I want the blue element to be on top.

From my understanding this is not possible using CSS's z-depth (like I attempted) since the elements are nested, but I can't seem to figure out a different way.

I would like to keep the HTML how it is, if possible, and do this entirely in CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do put other element outside of the parent

Comment: `    <div id="parent">
    <div id="other"></div>
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: you can use :before psuedo element of CSS for your child element and try

Answer (score 0):

just removed the `position:fixed` from `#parent`. You can add `position: static;` for `#parent`.

Please check this demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwZRMe

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not clear, so I'll recommend existing solutions.

First, you can move around elements using js, if you wish to not touch html. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7700174/5051731) link.

Secondly, this kind of functionality is closely related to `wrapping` of elements. This is present in [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) as well.

Thirdly, you may want to check out `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements.Checkout [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) link.

Answer (score 0):

**Nesting plays a big role for `z-index`.** If `#other` element sits on top of `#parent` element, a `#child` element of `#parent` can never be higher than `#other` element. This is an important rule for `z-index`.

In this case, you can change your HTML code in the following ways to create the shape you want.

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  z-index: 0;
  
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#other {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
  <div id="other"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  z-index: 0;
  
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#other {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<div id="child"></div>
<div id="other"></div>
```

**EDIT:** To keep the HTML, no need to use any `position` style for `#parent` and remove `top|left|z-index` values too in it.

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#other {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="other"></div>
```

Comment: He wan't to keep the same HTML. He needs to do this entirely in CSS.

Comment: @Sarbaz thanks for feedback. I didn't pay attention to that expectation. I've updated the answer now.